# Why does max_connections in my.ini not match concurrent connections in Mysql instance config wizard?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.1, max-connections, windows-server

MySQL 5.1.x | Windows Server 2003

Can someone please clarify why `max_connections` in my.ini is much larger than the manual value I specify in the [Concurrent Connections Dialogue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-connections.html)?

For example, if I set concurrent connections to 800 in the dialogue window, I see `max_connections=1023` in my.ini.  Why? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

`max_connections` is a global variable which will retain this value until you change it in `my.ini` and restart MySQL service.

Whereas concurrent connections can be measured by `max_used_connections` status variable which will vary based number of concurrent connections on your MySQL server.
This value is used to calculate `Highest number of concurrent connections`.
i.e. If this value is say 1000 and after sometime if number of concurent connections drops still this status variable will show 1000 until you execute `Flush status` query on your server.

To know exactly how many connections are open currently, you should check `Threads_connected` status variable.